# transfer file to and fro between two android phones without using the internet

Tags: android, gprs

I have an application that sends an SMS from one android to another which then processes the information contained in the sms. The problem is that the sms can only carry a small amount of data. I want to transfer larger files (probably no more than 1Mb) between two phones but without using the internet. I am thinking maybe GPRS, in which case can anyone give me some pointers on general coding issues with GPRS I would need to consider in order to do this and to get me started. Or anyone have any other ideas on how to do this?

Edit: Sorry, just to make it clearer, I need to access the mobile via some address such as its phone number to download a file and it could be anywhere, so bluetooth will not work unless it's in the vicinity (right?). Perhaps something like a modem or fax will do it if there is such a thing. I'm amazed this is so difficult to do, seems to be what mobiles were devised to do.

Comment: What about using the [bluetooth?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: Gprs too is internet but using your mobile operator

Answer (score 1):

I don't think GPRS would work.

It relies on mobile operator cells spread across (It costs and I think you're not allowed to send arbitrary packets).

Should it work on long distances? If not, bluetooth or [WiFi direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) would be the option.

Comment: Wifi direct looks interesting, I shall investigate, thanks. I guess I should have made it clear that I want to be able to locate a specific mobile, via its number, then take a file from it. So bluetooth is only for use in the vicinity. Perhaps something like a fax or modem is what I need. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Near Field Communication](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html) could be also be an answer to you solution if you are talking about transfer over short range.

Answer (score -1):

Use bluetooth to transfer the file

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mailBody);//mail body is your content         
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Comment: additionally add the privilage req. in mainfest file